# EntityFrameworkCore: how to reverse lookup entities with ForeignKey?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I have two entities:

```
public class Org : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public class Portfolio : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public virtual Org Organization { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    }
```

When I retrieve Portfolio data inside web api controller, I can do: `dbSet.Include(a=>a.Organization)` to load the related `Org` data. Is there a way to "reverse" this lookup from within the Org (to load all `Portfolio` that have foreignkeys to the Org being looked at)?

When I add a `List<Portfolio> Portfolios {get;set;}` property, I run into the loop reference endless loop: I assume because the two entities cross-reference each other.

The way I retrieve the data is this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

`OrgRepo.AllIncluding(a=>a.Portfolios)`

Comment: You can create a property List<Portfolio> in Org class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as adding a list of Portfolio to Org.

```
public class Org : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List <Portfolio> Portfolios  { get; set; } //Note, the naming should be plural, to indicate one to many
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships has more info on this too.

Comment: When I do this and then .Include the Portfolio, I bump into "Self referencing loop detected for property 'organization'" since the Org looks up Portfolios and Portfolios look up Orgs :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization should give you some assistance on that!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
   public class Org : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Portfolio> Portfolios  { get; set; }
    }

    public class Portfolio : BaseEntity, IEntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public virtual Org Organization { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    }
```

**Use:**

```
var orgs= _context.Portfolios.Include(a=>a.Organization).select(s=>s.Organization);
var portfolios= _context.Orgs .Include(a=>a.Portfolios).SelectMany(s=>s.Portfolios);
```